# Using two-way binding and angular2-markdown module

Tags: angular, web, markdown

I have an app that uses angular-2 markdown. Whatever user type in the textarea with the right format of markdown, the page should display the preview at runtime below. Just like writing questions in stackoverflow. Here is my form in html:

```
<div class="row align-row">
  <div class="col-md-6">

   <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">

  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="post" rows="15" placeholder="Enter your post" [(ngModel)]="post.post" name="post" required></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
  </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <p>Preview</p>
    <markdown>
    {{ post.post }}
  </markdown>

 </div>
</div>
```

And here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from './../../services/post.service';
import { CategoryService } from './../../services/category.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-post',
  templateUrl: './create-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-post.component.css']
})
export class CreatePostComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  post = {};

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService, private postService: 
PostService) { 
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
   }

  save(post){
    this.postService.create(post);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I have successfully implemented and installed markdown module. The problem is, there is no preview. I see the preview without `<markdown></markdown>` but not with it.

Comment: If you take a closer look at the documentation, you can do this using the service, not direct interpolation as you are doing: https://github.com/dimpu/angular2-markdown

Comment: Well either service or ```<markdown [data]="marked"></markdown>``` solved the problem. Anyway, if you move your comment to answer box, I'll mark your solution as an answer.

Comment: @GoGo I tried to install the plugin, it works in app.component.html only adding it to any other component gives markdown element error. Can you please let me know how did you use it in other component?

Comment: Make sure that in your `index.html` which is the entry point page has the following codes: `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async
    src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
  </script>` then add `<markdown>markdown code </markdown>`to your component.html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well either `service` or `<markdown [data]="marked"></markdown>` solved the problem